# Facebook as Auth Provider - no username or email passed in Auth.Data

Tags: authentication, facebook, auth-provider

I've been trying to setup auth provider login with facebook. I've followed the instructions online, have generated an authentication handler and customised.

However when I try logging in (through community) the facebook Auth.UserData passed into createUser method does not contain a username, email, first name or last name. It does however have the full name.

Is there something in the config (either Salesforce side or within my Facebook app) that I am missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

Fill the field 'User Info Endpoint URL' (on Auth provider page ) with this and test it out. 
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email

Reason for suggestion is:
Facebook api v2.2, 2.3 returns first name, last name, email etc by default. 
Facebook api v2.4 and later versions don't return these fields unless we specify /me?fields=first_name,last_name,email

Comment: Flawless man! Thanks for that! Was really searching hard for this!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the username or email. You can get the email by doing this

```
 data.attributeMap.get('email');
```

Comment: Thanks PepeFloyd, but data.attributeMap.get('email') returns null also. Looping through all the key/values in data.attributeMap and it contains only 'id' and 'sfdc_networkid'.

Comment: Are you using the default auth provider config or did you create your own fb app?

Comment: I've created by own fb app. Within auth providers settings I have Authorize Endpoint URL, Token Endpoint URL, User Info Endpoint URL, Default Scopes, Custom Error URL, Custom Logout URL all blank. I thought it could be Default Scopes, but if I enter a value in there (e.g. id or refresh_token full) I get an "We can’t log you in because of the following error.
No_Oauth_Code: Exchange code was not returned" error whilst trying to login.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your app settings, it works fine with the default settings.